# How to integrate WebSync with ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, comet

As the title said, I want to **use WebSync**, from [frozenmountain](http://www.frozenmountain.com/), **with my ASP.NET MVC 4**, but I haven't found any tutorial about it. Do you know **how to do that**, **where to start**? Or if you have any better way to implement `comet` with ASP.NET MVC 4, please let me know.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do you know how to do that, where to start?

The documentation is usually the first place you might start at when you need to apprehend some new tool or framework that you are not familiar with: http://docs.frozenmountain.com/websync4/

> Or if you have any better way to implement comet with ASP.NET MVC 4, please let me know.

You might checkout [`SignalR`](http://signalr.net/).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll take a look at SignalR. Do you have any example about SignalR with MVC?
**Edit** I've found the example, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a route in Global.asax (Application_Start):

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    // Add this line.
    WebSyncServer.AddRoute("websync");

    // ...
}
```

You can test it by browsing to:

```
 http://yourserver/websync
```

http://docs.frozenmountain.com/websync4/index.html#class=websync-getting-started-creating-the-server-10_basic-setup